# Can I make a contract call to refund the unused gas fee to a specific address instead of the msg.sender?

Tags: gas, etherscan, evm, cpp-ethereum

Can I make a contract call to refund the unused gas fee to a specific address instead of the `msg.sender`? I want to use this as a means of charging fees for my project.